# FuelPHPのインストール後、publicにアクセスしてもWelcomページが表示されない

Tags: php, fuelphp

はじめまして。プログラミング初心者です。
質問内容に至らない部分も多いかと思いますが、助けていただきたく、投稿させていただきます。

ローカルでの開発環境です。
FuelPHPのインストール後、localhost:8888/パス名/publicにアクセスしたものの
Welcomeページが表示されず404.phpに遷移しているようです。
諸々解決策を試してみましたが、Welcomeページが表示されず解決できておりません。
お手数ですが、お心当たりのある方は、解決方法をお教えいただけませんでしょうか。

**開発環境**

- Fuel: 1.8.2 running in "development" mode
- PHP 7.3.24-
- MAMP 6.3

**起こっている事象**

FuelPHPインストール後、Welcomページを表示させようとしたところ404.php画面が表示されている

画面表示内容

> Huh?We can't find that!
> The controller generating this page is found at APPPATH/classes/controller/welcome.php.
> This view is located at APPPATH/views/welcome/404.php.
> Page rendered in 0.0837s using 2.677mb of memＯＲy.
> FuelPHP is released under the MIT license.
> Version: 1.8.2

**試したこと**

1. ログファイル確認

   - 結果：ログ記述なし
2. デフォルトルートをrouts.phpにて確認

   - 結果：特に変更しておらず異常な記述は見当たらず
3. 404NotFoundのため、そもそもindex.phpおよびhello.phpファイルが存在するか確認

   - 結果：
     fuel/app/views/welcomeディレクトリ配下に存在
     直接パスを入力するも表示されず
4. FuelPHPのクイックインストール後、composerの記述指示があったため試す。

   - クイックインストール時の内容

     ```
     　24 package suggestions were added by new dependencies, use `composer suggest` to see details.
     　Generating autoload files
     　3 packages you are using are looking fＯＲ funding.
     　Use the `composer fund` commＡＮＤ to find out mＯＲe!
     ```
   - 結果：
     composer suggestおよびcomposer fundを試した後、
     composer.pharのＵＰＤＡＴＥ指示があったもののアップデートにエラー。
     Welcom表示はされないまま。
5. FuelPHPの手動インストール

   - 結果：
     上記クイックインストール時と同じ状態になりcomposer.pharのアップデートにエラー
     Welcom表示はされないまま
6. FuelPHPとPHPのバージョン相性を確認
   インストールしたFuelPHP1.8.2はPHP7.3に対応しているため、問題なしと判断

これ以上、確認する項目も思い浮かばず
手詰まりの状態となっております。
お手数をおかけしますが、ご教授いただけますと幸甚です。

---

2021/5/19 12:22追記

・プロファイリングの実行
FuelPHPのプロファイリングを実行した結果、error等は見当たりませんでした。
[image: プロファイリング]

・直接パス名を入力
上記3にて直接パス名を入力するもwelcomeページが反映されなかったと記載しましたが
パス名が誤っておりました。
ただし、下記を実行するとwelcomeページは表示されるものの、CSSが反映されていないように思います。
http://localhost:8888/パス名/public/index.php/welcome/index
[image: welcomeページ]

また、直接パス名を入力したのち、index.php以下のパス名を省き
http://localhost:8888/パス名/public/ で入力しましたが、welcomeページは変わらず表示されませんでした。

---

2021/5/19 15:31追記

ディレクトリ確認とドキュメントルートの設定について
ドキュメントルートの設定：設定済み
ディレクトリを確認：未確認　でした。
ディレクトリ確認した結果 .htaccessというファイルがないことがわかりました。
ただディレクトリ確認のページに記載されていたoil refine install を実行しても、
再度手動インストールやクイックインストールをしても、.htaccessファイルは追加されずという状況です。
ちなみに、publicフォルダ内は下部添付内容となっており、.htaccessというファイルはなく、web.configというファイルが存在しております。
※画像はドキュメントルートの設定をしていない状態です。
[image: publicフォルダ]

Comment: 環境かアプリのどっちの問題か切り分けのために、[プロファイリング](http://fuelphp.jp/docs/1.6/general/profiling.html)をしてみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: >>keitaro_soさん
ご回答ありがとうございます
プロファイリングを実行してみた結果、error表示は出ておらず、このような表記となっておりました。
この場合、環境の問題の可能性ということになるのでしょうか？

105.693 msFuel\Core\Request::__construct Start route lookup
SPEED 
108.387 msFuel\Core\Request::__construct End route lookup
SPEED 
108.400 msFuel\Core\Request::execute: Start of welcome/404
SPEED 
113.487 msFuel\Core\Request::execute: End of welcome/404
SPEED

Comment: プロファイリングで実行した新しい情報は質問に追記してください

Comment: >>keitaro_satoさん
失礼しました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。追記いたします。

Comment: クイックインストールの後は[ディレクトリを確認](https://fuelphp.com/docs/installation/instructions.html#/structure)、[ドキュメントルートの設定](https://fuelphp.com/docs/installation/instructions.html#/install_inside_root)を行いますがこれを実施しましたか？

Comment: >>keitaro_satoさん
ドキュメントルートの設定は行なっていたのですが、ディレクトリの確認はできておりませんでした。
ディレクトリを確認した結果、 .htaccessというファイルがないことがわかりました。
ただディレクトリ確認のページに記載されていたoil refine install を実行しても、再度手動インストールやクイックインストールをしても、.htaccessファイルは追加されずという状況です。質問にもその旨、追記しておきます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ドキュメントルートの設定を行ったと書いてありますが、
http://localhost:8888/パス名/public/index.php/welcome/index
でアクセスして見れているということは、
ドキュメントルート以下のディレクトリにそのままfuelインストールしたのかと見受けられます。

Fuelのドキュメントを確認すると[参考](https://fuelphp.com/docs/installation/instructions.html#/structure)

> the public directory in the source equals your web server's public document directory.

インストールしたpublicのディレクトリがドキュメントルートになるフレームワークになっています。

> For security reasons, it is strongly advised NOT to install Fuel inside your webserver's document root.

またセキュリティを理由としてFuelアプリケーションのすべてをウェブの公開領域（ドキュメントルート）以下に置くべきではないと推奨されています。

まずはそちらを検討してみてください。

もしどうしても、下のディレクトリに置きたい場合は
[こちら](https://fuelphp.com/docs/installation/instructions.html#/install_inside_root2)を参考にしてもらってWebサーバの設定の変更が必要です。

Comment: 大変助かりました！
記載いただいた通り、ドキュメントルート以下のディレクトリにそのままfuelインストールしておりました。
本当にありがとうございます。
英語の文章だったので細かい部分までは読み飛ばしてしまっておりました。
以後気をつけます。
ありがとうございました！